# Send user input as parameter to rails link_to method

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have following code in my view:

```
<span class="pull-right">
      <%= link_to 'Siblings', siblings_path(cnic: '21303-51235-5'), id: 'view_siblings' %>
</span>
<%= f.text_field :cnic, class: "form-control" %>
```

As for now i have given fixed value to cnic parameter. 
What i want is:

> If user type his cnic then this user input should be sent as parameter
>   to siblings_path.

How can i do that?

Comment: you need a litlle bit javascript.. or you can change with a form..

Comment: How can i do that via javascript?

Comment: why not wrap it in a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".form-control").change(function(e) {
  $("#view_siblings").prop("href", siblings_path + "?cnic=" + e.target.value);
  // replace siblings_path with actual url
})
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, add some description how it solves the problem. It helps future readers.